# Quality deterioration on a device

Tags: unity, color, aspect-ratio

I am using Unity. When I try the game out in the IDE everything looks pretty good:

[image]

But when I am trying to play the same game on a device the quality becomes a great deal worse and you can see it for yourself:

[image]

I am using Xiame Redmi 4X and I do not think that it is because of device.

So, how can I fix it? How can I preserve the quality?

I would like to try out [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1162252/losing-image-quality-in-android-after-build.html) solution, but there is no Android settings in my Inspector for quality:

[image]

I would like to preserve at least colors.

And here are setting for my player sprites:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The render quality settings apply mostly to 3d games. Very few of the features you would usually use in a 2d game are affected by them.

It seems like your play-window uses a different resolution than your device. Click on "16:9" in the upper left corner of the play window, and set it to a custom resolution which is identical to your target device. You should now see the same degration due to scaling which you see on the device and then should be able to troubleshoot it properly.

Regarding *why* there is that degration: There are a couple of possible reasons. But which one is responsible in your specific case is hard to tell without seeing how you set up your camera, how you render your sprites, etc.

But keep in mind that it wouldn't be wise to look for a solution which looks good on that particular resolution but not on any others, because Android devices come in all kinds of screen resolutions. To keep the image quality ideal you should try to always keep the scaling 1:1 no matter what resolution you have. But that means the amount of game world which is visible on the screen depends on the screen resolution, so different devices will have different game experiences. There is no silver bullet solution to this conundrum. You will have to find a game-specific compromise.

Comment: My phone resolution is 16:9. It is the most appropriate. Could it be due to me setting pixels per unit of my player to 450?

Comment: If setting 1:1 resolution how can I make the game appropriate for at least my device which has 16:9 resolution?

Comment: @ЯрикТроф 16:9 is an *aspect ratio* not a *screen resolution*. According to [this website](http://www.gsmarena.com/xiaomi_redmi_4_(4x)-8608.php), the screen resolution of the Xiame Redmi 4X is 720 x 1280 pixels.

Comment: So, does that mean that I should set my aspect ratio to be 9:16?

Comment: @ЯрикТроф No, it means you need to set your play window to a **fixed resolution** of 720 vertical pixels and 1280 horizontal pixels. If you  set it to an aspect ratio (*any* aspect ratio) it will keep that ratio but change the resolution depending on the size of the play window.

Comment: Is it a good idea to set resolution to 1280 by 720 but change Default orientation to the landscape left?

Comment: @ЯрикТроф That depends on whether you would like your game to be played in landscape mode or portrait mode. But as I wrote, your goal should be to make the game work properly with *any* screen resolution.

Comment: Ok, got it. Could you please look at my sprite settings? Are they alright? What could make my colors that dark and bad looking?